# How to Split a Line that have multiple separators?

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I want to parse a line similar to the one below.

> First Class Mail (Canada) (15.00)

From the above line I want only 15.00

How do I use the `string.Split();`?

Comment: `string str = "First Class Mail (Canada) (15.00)".Split(new[] { "(Canada)" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");` would give you `15.00`

Comment: Will all the strings you'll use it with be in exactly the same format as your example? What will change from string to string and what will stay the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why split if you don't want the items?

If that is the case then use a regular expression to extract the value of 15.00. The below pattern basically says find a set of numbers with a period, specified in a `set` pattern of `[\d.]`Following that is a `+` which says *of the set previous* match 1 to or more of them. Using that pattern it will capture the numeric part of your sentence.

```
Regex.Match("First Class Mail (Canada) (15.00)", @"[\d.]+").Value
```

But, if other numbers might be in the sentence, one has to be be more specific with the `pattern` specification of the numbers. With that thought we will excactly spell out the number pattern instead of just finding it in a `set` above. Here we look for a digit, one or more, then a period, then two digits:

```
Regex.Match("1st Class Mail (Canada) (15.00)", @"\d+\.\d\d").Value
```

If you truly need the other items, then a new pattern can be created.

Comment: Thnq for ur answer.. I got correct answer what im expected .. It's really amazing.. +5

Answer (score 3):

I came up with something simple:

```
var str = "First Class Mail (Canada) (15.00)";
var result = str.Split(new[] {'(', ')'})[3];
```

This is under the assumption that all data is formatted the same.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I wouldn't use this method because it's hard for me to follow due to positional indexing and non-natural (i.e. splitting on both open/close token) separation; it is also more brittle than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var str = "First Class Mail (Canada) (15.00)";
var result = str.Split(new[] {' ', '(', ')'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .First(x => x.Replace(".", "").All(char.IsDigit));
```

Comment: @user3311715 try again with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "First Class Mail (Canada) (15.00)";
        var array = Regex.Split(str, @"[^0-9\.]+")
    .Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "");
```